Joomla 4 Route::_ not generating SEF link when linking to other custom components
I have a problem which will no doubt be user error on my end but am having no luck figuring out what it is. I have a site with several custom components - eg com_bookings and com_contacts.
If I use this PHP in my tmpl view whilst in com_bookings from another view within that component:
Route::_('index.php?option=com_bookings&view=calendar')
That will generate the correct SEF link becuase I am using the Route whilst in the same component (for example on the my bookings page). This is great!
However, when I want to link to a view that is in another component - lets say Route::_('index.php?option=com_contact&view=myenquiries'), then the Route wont pick up the menu item that exists for that page and instead will do a bad SEF link like "component/contact/myenquiries&Itemid=123" (Where 123 in the Homepage of the website).
This is a problem for me because it is not allowing me to determine the template on that page, and also modules etc can't be assigned. Running indentical Route code from within the com_contact component will work completely fine.
Currently I am having to hardcode the URLs in the view when linking between platforms, but I would much rather use Joomla routing to make this work. Do I need to code up a script that firstly looks through all the menu items to see if there is a match for that component to then get the ItemId for example? Or is there a built in Route::_ function I can use to get this going?
Perhaps there is an update that I can make in the Router.php file that I am missing that allows the Route to pick up rules or menu items that alread exist when linking from an external component?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I realise this question is a bit old - did you get it sorted? This feature should work ok. I'm just a bit confused because you say you have com_contacts as a custom component and then you mention com_contact (without the s). This is a standard Joomla component so you shouldn't have a custom component of the same name. If you're routing to com_contact then you need to have set up a menuitem for the Joomla com_contact component, as opposed to one for a custom com_contacts component.
